# I’m trying to texture paint for the first time, and was wondering if there was a way to set brush size?

Tags: mesh, texturing, texture-painting

I’m trying to texture paint a sphere for a globe, but I realized after a bit that the brush size is set to the view not to a scale. When I zoom in or out it stays the same size, but affects the object differently. By zooming out I can cover almost half of the sphere, and by zooming in make more fine details. A useful feature in itself, but doesn’t work for what I need.

Comment: there's an option for the scultp brushes, you can switch the brush radius from View to Scene, I don't think it exists for Texture Painting so maybe you should suggest it in the Right Click Select site: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/

Comment: If you witch to the 2D Image Editor, your brush will respect size in relation to the image texture being painted on. In the 3D editor, your paint will work as you describe - you can block out basic areas of rough painting there and use the 2D Image Editor to do the controlled painting if you want.